# change color on hover

Tags: html, css

```
String mailData = " <html> "
            + "   <head> "
            + " <script>"
            + " </script>"
            + "   <style> "
            + "  button:hover{background-color:#00ffff;color:#00ffff;font-style: italic;} "
            + " table{border-collapse: collapse;} "
            + "    #th1{ width:5cm;height:1cm;text-align:center;background-color:#00ffff;border:2px solid;} "
            + " #td1{text-align:center;background-color:#00ffff;border:2px solid;} "
            + " a:link, a:visited { "
            + "     background-color: #003333; "
            + "     color: white; "
            + "     padding: 14px 25px; "
            + "     text-align: center;  "
            + "     text-decoration: none;  "
            + "     display: inline-block;  "
            + " } "
            + " a:hover, a:active {  "
            + "     background-color: #2eb82e;"
            + "   color: #ffffff "
            + " } "
            + "   </style> "
            + "   </head> "
            + " <body style=' background-color:white;color:blue'> "
            + " <div  style='border:1px solid black ;background-color:white;  '> "
            + " <table> " + " <tr><td><p >&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Hello <b>"
            + 5645
            + "<b><br><br> </p></td></tr> "
            + " <tr><td><p >"
            + "&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+56456
            + "-"
            +   636
            + " has submitted a leave request today with the following details :"
            + " </p><br><br></td></tr></table> "
            + " <table border='border' style='margin:0px auto;'> "
            + "  <tr style='width:5cm;height:1cm;text-align:left;background-color: #009999;border:2px solid;color:white;'> "
            + tableHeader
            + "  </tr> "
            + " <tr style='width:5cm;height:1cm;text-align:left;background-color: #9f9fdf;border:2px solid;color:white;'> "
            + tableData
            + "  </tr> "

            + "<table style='margin:0px auto;' >"
            + "         <tr>"
            + " <td style='border:none;background-color:white;width:3cm;'>"
            +"<br><br>"
            + "  <a  href='"
            + 546456
            + "' ><b>Approve<b></a>"
            + " </td>"
            + " <td style='border:none;background-color:white;width:3cm;'>"
            +"<br><br>"
            +"  <a  href='"+ url+"' ><b>Reject<b></a>" 
            + "           </td> </tr> "

            + "  </table> "
            + "<br><br><br>"
            + "<center><b>Click on above Approve/Reject button to Approve/Reject this leave request or login to https://my.thbs.com to Approve/Reject the same.</b></center><br><br><br>"

            + " <br> "
            + "<div style='margin-left:1cm;color:black' >Regards,<br>MIS"
            + "<br>"
            + "<br>"
            + "<b style='color:red'>Note:</b>         The purpose of this email is to Approve/Reject a leave request directly through mailbox reducing the effort to login to <b style='color:blue'>https://my.thbs.com.</b>"
            + "This is an auto generated email."
            + "Please do not reply or forward this Email as the information inside this email is not supposed to be disclosed."
            + "Incase of FWD then recipient can also Approve/Reject the request."
            + "        </div>" + " </div> " + " </body> " + " </html> ";
```

Here i have two approve and reject buttons which changes color to green on hover.My requirement is to change green color when i hover over approve button and red  when reject button.what changes do i have to make?

Comment: Where is your reject "button"? I can only see an Approve button

Comment: added..................

Comment: Hi Saurabh, please try to adhere to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): All the string formatting is not important to ask the question, only the html/css matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to reject button and override the hyperlink style.

We can add class to Hyperlink as follow.

```
<a href="#" class="some_class">Some text</a>
```

Now we use the class to style the specific element as follow.

```
a.some_class {
   /* Your styles goes here */
}
a.some_class:hover {
   /* Your hover styles goes here */
}
```

Refer following code.

```
String mailData = " <html> "
            + "   <head> "
            + " <script>"
            + " </script>"
            + "   <style> "
            + "  button:hover{background-color:#00ffff;color:#00ffff;font-style: italic;} "
            + " table{border-collapse: collapse;} "
            + "    #th1{ width:5cm;height:1cm;text-align:center;background-color:#00ffff;border:2px solid;} "
            + " #td1{text-align:center;background-color:#00ffff;border:2px solid;} "
            + " a:link, a:visited { "
            + "     background-color: #003333; "
            + "     color: white; "
            + "     padding: 14px 25px; "
            + "     text-align: center;  "
            + "     text-decoration: none;  "
            + "     display: inline-block;  "
            + " } "
            + " a:hover, a:active {  "
            + "     background-color: #2eb82e;"
            + "   color: #ffffff "
            + " } "
            + " a.rejectBtn:hover, a.rejectBtn:active {  "
            + "     background-color: #ff0000;"
            + "   color: #ffffff "
            + " } "
            + "   </style> "
            + "   </head> "
            + " <body style=' background-color:white;color:blue'> "
            + " <div  style='border:1px solid black ;background-color:white;  '> "
            + " <table> " + " <tr><td><p >&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Hello <b>"
            + 5645
            + "<b><br><br> </p></td></tr> "
            + " <tr><td><p >"
            + "&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+56456
            + "-"
            +   636
            + " has submitted a leave request today with the following details :"
            + " </p><br><br></td></tr></table> "
            + " <table border='border' style='margin:0px auto;'> "
            + "  <tr style='width:5cm;height:1cm;text-align:left;background-color: #009999;border:2px solid;color:white;'> "
            + tableHeader
            + "  </tr> "
            + " <tr style='width:5cm;height:1cm;text-align:left;background-color: #9f9fdf;border:2px solid;color:white;'> "
            + tableData
            + "  </tr> "

            + "<table style='margin:0px auto;' >"
            + "         <tr>"
            + " <td style='border:none;background-color:white;width:3cm;'>"
            +"<br><br>"
            + "  <a  href='"
            + 546456
            + "' ><b>Approve<b></a>"
            + " </td>"
            + " <td style='border:none;background-color:white;width:3cm;'>"
            +"<br><br>"
            +"  <a  href='"+ url+"' class='rejectBtn' ><b>Reject<b></a>" 
            + "           </td> </tr> "

            + "  </table> "
            + "<br><br><br>"
            + "<center><b>Click on above Approve/Reject button to Approve/Reject this leave request or login to https://my.thbs.com to Approve/Reject the same.</b></center><br><br><br>"

            + " <br> "
            + "<div style='margin-left:1cm;color:black' >Regards,<br>MIS"
            + "<br>"
            + "<br>"
            + "<b style='color:red'>Note:</b>         The purpose of this email is to Approve/Reject a leave request directly through mailbox reducing the effort to login to <b style='color:blue'>https://my.thbs.com.</b>"
            + "This is an auto generated email."
            + "Please do not reply or forward this Email as the information inside this email is not supposed to be disclosed."
            + "Incase of FWD then recipient can also Approve/Reject the request."
            + "        </div>" + " </div> " + " </body> " + " </html> ";
```

Comment: I feel like it's more helpful to explain what this is doing than just handing over a working version... and an ID would probably suffice in this case rather than a class. Ideally you would have a class for buttons, then an id for the reject and approve buttons differences.

Comment: I've written what to do on the top of the code for him to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
+ "  <a  href='"
+ 546456
+ "' ><b>Approve<b></a>"
+ " </td>"
+ " <td style='border:none;background-color:white;width:3cm;'>"
+"<br><br>"
+"  <a  href='"+ url+"' ><b>Reject<b></a>"
```

to this

```
+ "  <a onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundcolor='#ff0000'\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundcolor='#003333'\" href='"
+ 546456
+ "' ><b>Approve<b></a>"
+ " </td>"
+ " <td style='border:none;background-color:white;width:3cm;'>"
+"<br><br>"
+"  <a onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundcolor='#00ff00'\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundcolor='#003333'\" href='"+ url+"' ><b>Reject<b></a>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your buttons do not distinguish between each other so they both use the same formatting. You can give each button an `id` property that you can then give it's own css.

For example, you could make the buttons

```
<a id="approveBtn" href="something">   
  <b>Approve</b>
</a>

<a id="rejectBtn" href="something">
  <b>Reject</b>
</a>
```

To distinguish between each button, then in your css you would have

```
#rejectBtn:hover 
{  
  background-color: #2ceg2f;
  color: #ffffff; 
} 

#approveBtn:hover 
{  
  background-color: #2eb82e;
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Or whatever colours you wanted.

Look at id's and classes for making similarly formatted html elements, classes for the generalised stuff (radius for button etc.) and id's for stuff unique to that instance (such as red for the reject, green for the approve)